# What language is the GPT-3 engine written in?

Tags: natural-language-processing, programming-languages, c++, gpt-3, c

I know that the API is python based, but what's the gpt-3 engine written in mostly? C? C++? I'm having some trouble finding this info.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The GPT-3 source code hasn’t been released but the creators say it uses the “same model and architecture as GPT-2” [(source)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165) with some exceptions.

The GPT-2 [source code](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2) is written in 100% Python. The model is based on Tensorflow and NumPy which are written using C and C++. My best guess is that GPT-3 is also written in Python using libraries based on C.